# Change variable name in jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm trying to get a JSON output using `jbuilder` that looks like this:

```
[{"correct_response": 0,
  "section_id": 1,
  "image_url": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/question/3/PreguntaWeb.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=r8COJLWNWABfwlm6BQ4ZpPlvFGw%3D&Expires=1401509509",
  "responses": [{
  "responseA": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/response/1/alternativaA.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=MkUUT7NuoHDH/BjiJdMiHV5f%2BB4%3D&Expires=1401509509"},
 {"responseB": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/response/2/alternativaB.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=EZ6KeqhzlwPGX1PAetvqR/GPH2M%3D&Expires=1401509509"},
 {"responseC": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/response/3/alternativaC.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=/Ntt6y4JrfVjjw0zpOKgIXtihvI%3D&Expires=1401509509"},
 {"responseD": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/response/4/alternativaD.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=Exrr0WTsSx2n3FixjwADiiwwPjM%3D&Expires=1401509509"},  
 {"responseAE": "https://850.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/response/5/alternativaE.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSKXBBJ4URBWSPUQ&Signature=udJ5jK/zG9ug8A6WwsnhYZRcsPk%3D&Expires=1401509509"}
]
}]
```

I think I'm close, but I don't know what is wrong with my code:

```
json.array!(@questions) do |json, question|
  json.extract! question, :correct_response, :section_id, :image_url

      json.responses question.responses do |response|
    [ 'responseA', 'responseB', 'responseC', 'responseD', 'responseE' ].each { |letter|
          response.set!(letter,  response.image_url )
        }
        end
  end
end
```

Someone has any suggestions?

Comment: What is the current output of your code?